# Macro to Run a Procedure Across Several Excel Worksheets

Tags: excel, row, copy-paste, worksheet, vba

I'm stuck with this problem. I need to run a macro that will do the following:

1. Find the last line in a table on the worksheet called "Baseline".
2. Add a row to that table
3. Copy the formats and formulas (but *not* values) from the row above to the new row.
4. Repeat the process for the other worksheets (called Quarter 1, Quarter 2 etc), that have the same structure as the worksheet called Baseline.

My problem is that the process only seems to work on the first worksheet, Baseline, but not on any of the other worksheets. I wonder if the problem is the way I have tried to get the code to copy formulas and formats only.

Here is the code, just for the Baseline and Quarter 1 worksheets:

```
Public Sub AddRow()

On Error GoTo errhandler

    Worksheets("Baseline").Activate


'Find Last Row in Service User Details

    Dim rgeLastRowBaseline As Range
    Set rgeLastRowBaseline = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Baseline").Cells.Find("Cost")


' Select and Copy Last Row

    rgeLastRowBaseline.End(xlDown).EntireRow.Select

    Selection.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert

    rgeLastRowBaseline.End(xlDown).EntireRow.Select

    Selection.Copy

    rgeLastRowBaseline.End(xlDown).Offset(1).EntireRow.Select

    rgeLastRowBaseline.End(xlDown).Offset(1).EntireRow.PasteSpecial

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Select
    Selection.ClearContents

'Quarter 1


    Worksheets("Quarter 1").Activate


    Dim rgeLastRowQ1 As Range
    Set rgeLastRowQ1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Quarter 1").Cells.Find("Cost")

' Select and Copy Last Row

    rgeLastRowQ1.End(xlDown).EntireRow.Select


    Selection.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert

    rgeLastRowQ1.End(xlDown).EntireRow.Select

    Selection.Copy

    rgeLastRowQ1.End(xlDown).Offset(1).EntireRow.Select

    rgeLastRowQ1.End(xlDown).Offset(1).EntireRow.PasteSpecial

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Select
    Selection.ClearContents


Exit Sub


errhandler:

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Does anyone have any suggestions please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `Worksheet` type variables. I did not correct your technical solutions even though I don't completely agree with selecting everything.

```
Sub onesheet(ws As Worksheet)
On Error GoTo errhandler
ws.Activate

Dim rgeLastRowQ1 As Range
Set rgeLastRowQ1 = ws.Cells.Find("Cost")
' Select and Copy Last Row

rgeLastRowQ1.End(xlDown).EntireRow.Select

Selection.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert

rgeLastRowQ1.End(xlDown).EntireRow.Select

Selection.Copy

rgeLastRowQ1.End(xlDown).Offset(1).EntireRow.Select

rgeLastRowQ1.End(xlDown).Offset(1).EntireRow.PasteSpecial

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Select
Selection.ClearContents
Exit Sub

errhandler:

Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Sub sheetloop()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "Baseline" Or ws.Name Like "Quarter*" Then Call onesheet(ws)
Next ws
End Sub
```